# How many ways are there to assign $20$ different people to $3$ different rooms with at least $1$ person in each room?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

How many ways are there to assign $20$ different people to $3$ different rooms with at least $1$ person in each room?

I know how to approach this problem using combinations:$$17!\cdot {3 \choose 1}$$But now I want to approach this problem using inclusion-exclusion set principles, but am unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: Where did your answer come from? I don't think it is correct

Comment: It isn't. Servaes gave a proper explanation as to why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can use inclusion-exclusion in the following wordy way:

There is only one way to distribute $20$ people over $1$ room. Given $3$ rooms, there are $3\times1=3$ ways to distribute $20$ people over a single room.

There are $2^{20}$ ways to distribute $20$ people over $2$ rooms. Given $3$ rooms, there are $3$ ways to pick $2$ rooms and hence $3\times2^{20}$ ways to distribute $20$ people over two rooms, though each of the $3\times1=3$ ways to distribute $20$ people over one rooms is now counted twice. So in fact there are
$$3\times2^{20}-3\times1=3\times(2^{20}-1),$$
ways to distribute $20$ people over $2$ of the $3$ rooms. Similarly, there are $3^{20}$ ways to distribute $20$ people over $3$ rooms. The count above shows that there are $3\times(2^{20}-1)$ ways to distribute $20$ people over $2$ of the $3$ rooms, so there remain
$$3^{20}-3\times(2^{20}-1)=3\times(3^{19}-2^{20}+1),$$
ways to distribute $20$ people over $3$ rooms with at least $1$ person in each room.

Comment: Very good for a first introduction to inclusion-exclusion. It was how I did it before learning about the general formula and why it works (everything cancels out exactly to leave only one term).

Comment: At the very last step, why is there still a remaining $3$ in $3\cdot (3^{19}-2^{20}+1)$?

Comment: I simply wrote $3^{20}=3\times 3^{19}$, if that's what you mean?

Comment: Ah... Maybe if I remembered algebra that would've helped.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that what you said you know is actually wrong. If there are only 3 people, you would get by your method a completely wrong answer, and it should be clear why it is wrong.

You need inclusion-exclusion here. How many ways to have at least 1 room empty? How many ways to have at least 2 rooms empty? If you $T$ be the collection of all possibilities, and let $S_k$ be the collection of possibilities with the $k$-th room empty, then the number of desired solutions is:

$|T| - |S_1| - |S_2| - |S_3| + |S_1 \cap S_2| + |S_1 \cap S_3| + |S_2 \cap S_3| - |S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3|$.

This can be simplified because by symmetry you know that:

$|S_1| = |S_2| = |S_3|$ and $|S_1 \cap S_2| = |S_1 \cap S_3| = |S_2 \cap S_3|$.

Note that each term is now easy to compute.

Comment: @Jodo1992: You're welcome. Note that the simple venn-diagram based intuition does not extend easily to the general case (say $k$ rooms), so you do need to learn how to do it the general way.

Comment: You mentioned that it ***can*** be simplified because of symmetry, but what exactly would it simplify to?

Comment: Let's say you have $n$ people and $r$ rooms, then the answer would be $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{r}{k} (r-k)^n$.

Comment: @Jodo1992: There's no way you could get that without essentially using the general inclusion-exclusion formula. Here $\binom{r}{k}$ is the number of terms that are the intersection of $k$ of the $r$ collections. Sorry the summation should be up to $r$, not $n$.

Comment: @Jodo1992: In case it wasn't clear, in this case it means that you only need to compute 4 terms. It is most important in the general case since usually you have similar kinds of symmetry, which would be necessary to reduce the number of terms from $2^r$ to just $r$. Otherwise the general formula wouldn't be very useful.